# Bestway to send data from servlet to client?

Tags: java, servlets

Guyz,

I have a servlet where i query data from mysql using jdbc.

I have a huge result set to send to client (atleast 3 column and 10 rows )

What would be the the best way to send instead simply writing to the response stream like below?

```
ResultSet toResults = toStatement.getResultSet();

        if (toResults.next()) {
            out.println(toResults.getString(1));
                    out.println(toResults.getString(2));
                    ....
                    ....

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First this does not sound the huge data. Second what you mean by client? If you have to display the data in Browser than you can create the List of VO's or List of string array.

If you are working on Ajax or your client is application, you can send data using XML or JSON.

Comment: okay my client is android - i usually do a read line of the response.. well the data i mentioned is the least - it will grow upto 100 and more.. what do you think?

Comment: Add the android tag to your question. Even with 100rows and 3 cols, if data does not contain big strings than its not *huge*. I have not tried android. Even if you have to send data by writing to stream, it will be good if you put in structure with JSON or XML. It will be easier to handle at the client side and doing changes in future will be easy.

Comment: Try JSON, easy to implement and efficient